# Does multiple condition coverage always imply branch coverage?

Tags: testing, code-coverage

Does multiple condition coverage imply branch coverage ?

I have been reading online for some comparisons between different coverage criteria, and I found some resources claim that multiple condition coverage doesn't necessarily imply branch coverage and others claim it does since it tests all possible combinations.

I understand that multiple condition coverage is difficult to achieve with short circuit logical operators, but I am not sure whether this is related to the comparison.

Comment: IMO, 100% Multiple Condition Coverage is 100% branch coverage but 100% branch coverage may not mean 100% MCC. As you mentioned, MCC covers all possible condtions. Hence, You take all possible branches as well

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not.

Logically it should, but you can have a defect in the code causing the condition evaluate always to, for example, false, despite the combinations of sub-conditions.
E.g. (from Bullseye.com):

```
bool f(bool e) { return false; }
bool a[2] = { false, false };
if (f(a && b)) ...
if (a[int(a && b)]) ...
if ((a && b) ? false : false)
```

Comment: In this example you will not have 100% MCC coverage since there are infeasible paths (and consequently you may not necessarily have 100% branch coverage either).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Multiple condition coverage (MCC) implies branch coverage.

Unlike plain condition coverage the MCC metric deals with all combinations of conditions that influence a **decision**. And decisions control branching.

In that sense multiple condition coverage is very similar to [MC/DC](https://www.froglogic.com/coco/modified-condition-decision-coverage-mcdc/).

Comment: Note that this is only true if you have 100% MCC coverage. Thus, 100% MCC implies 100% branch coverage. But at 50% MCC you cannot say anything about what percentage branch coverage you have.